# Updating MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I'm using [easyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/). I'm trying to update the records in my database but I keep getting `<?php echo $btitle; ?>` and `<?php echo $bauthor; ?>` written in the text boxes in my HTML form and data isn't updated but it does print "Updated data successfully".

Here's my form code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <title>Update Book</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Update Your Library</h1>
        <form method = "post" action = "editBook.php">
            <?php
            $conn = mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "");
            $db = mysql_select_db ("library", $conn);
            $query = "select * from Books where No = ". $_GET['bid'];
            $result = mysql_query($query, $conn);

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                $bid = $row ['bid'];
                $btitle = $row ['btitle'];
                $bauthor = $row ['bauthor'];
            }

            mysql_close($conn);
            ?>
            <table>
                <input type="hidden" name="bid" size="5" value="<?php echo $bid;?>">
                <tr>
                    <td>Title:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="btitle" size="100"value="<?php echo $btitle;?>"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Author:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="bauthor" size="100" value="<?php echo $bauthor;?>"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Update">
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php
    $dbhost = '127.0.0.1';
    $dbuser = 'root';
    $dbpass = '';

    $bid=$_POST['bid'];
    $btitle=$_POST['btitle'];
    $bauthor=$_POST['bauthor'];

    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    mysql_select_db('library');

    if(! $conn ) { 
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $sql = "update  books
            set Title='$btitle',
                Author='$bauthor'
            where book_id='$bid'";

    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

    if(! $retval ) {
        die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    print "updated data successfully\n";

    mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Sounds like the form page is not being executed by PHP.

Comment: If you do `View Source` on the form page, do you see all the PHP code?

Comment: No I only see the form code.

Comment: But you see `value="<?php echo $btitle ?>"` in the input field?

Comment: `<?php echo &bid; ?>` the `&` should be `$`. You should be getting a syntax error from that.

Comment: In your `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))` loop, you're overwriting the variables each time. So your form will just have the values from the last row that the query selects, not all the results of the query. If that's what you want, why don't you just use `LIMIT 1` in the query and just fetch one row?

Comment: Yes I do see value="<?php echo $btitle ?>"

Comment: Please post your actual source code. What you posted is obviously not right, because `<?php echo &bid; ?>` would cause a Parse error and nothing would be executed.

Comment: What is the extention of your file? Not all files are parsed by php. Try changing it to .php. I had a similar issue on a server - `.html` file got parsed by PHP, `.htm` file was skipped.

Comment: Yes, now the text boxes are fine but still my records cannot be updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the files does not get parsed by PHP. The problem may be a filename extention not defined in configuration.

On other hand I see another problem which may raise when the first issue is solved. Viariables which hold information are out of scope. This will lead to empty answer.

When you read from database:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$bid = $row ['bid'];
$btitle = $row ['btitle'];
$bauthor = $row ['bauthor'];
}
```

those 3 variables are created in the while(){} scope and they do not exist outside of it. Just initialize them with empty string before the loop in the main scope:

```
$bid = $btitle = $bauthor = '';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$bid = $row ['bid'];
$btitle = $row ['btitle'];
$bauthor = $row ['bauthor'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This ::**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = "utf-8">
<title>Update Book</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Update Your Library</h1>
<form method = "post" action = "save.php">
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$db = mysql_select_db("library", $conn);
$query = "select * from Books where No = " . $_GET['bid'];
$result = mysql_query($query, $conn);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    $bid = $row['bid'];
    $btitle = $row['btitle'];
    $bauthor = $row['bauthor'];
    }

?>

<table>
<input type="hidden" name="bid" size="5" value="<?php echo (isset($bid))?$bid:'';?>">
<tr><td>Title:</td><td><input type="text" name="btitle" size="100" value="<?php echo (isset($btitle))?$btitle:'';?>"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Author:</td><td><input type="text" name="bauthor" size="100" value="<?php echo (isset($bauthor))?$bauthor:'';?>"></td></tr>
</table>
<p><input type="submit" value="Update"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>

  <?php
    mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Don't just dump a bunch of code. Explain what you think the problem was, and how you're fixing it.

Comment: I still keep getting ?phpecho $btitle; ? inside the text boxes, also with this code I get after I submit anything "Object not found".

Comment: @LinaGz just to echo the   $bid   $btitle and  $bauthor ,,, after  the while loop complete ... i want to check its get the values or not

Comment: It prints nothing in the form

Comment: I tried the updated code, still the same problem, ?php echo (isset($btitle))?$btitle:'';? appears on the text box and If I click submit "Object not found"